Modulus of continuity near $0$
Define the modulus of continuity of a continuous function $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ by $\omega(h)=\sup\{|f(t)-f(s)|:\,|t-s|\leq h\}$.
It is clear that $\omega$ is continuous, $\omega(0)=0$, it is increasing, but is not necessarily strictly increasing (take for example $f(t)=\sin(10t)$). Unless $f$ is constant, $\omega$ can not be constant on an interval containing $0$. My question: is $\omega$ necessarily strictly increasing on an interval containing $0$, unless $f$ is constant? That is, does there exist $\epsilon>0$, such that $\omega$ is strictly increasing on $[0,\epsilon]$?

The answer is negative. Let $f$  be the Cantor function. I will show first that then the restriction of $\omega$ to $\left[\frac13,\frac49\right]$ is constant.
My first step will consist in proving that $\omega\left(\frac49\right)=\frac12$. Take $0\leqslant s\leqslant t\leqslant1$ such that $t-s\leqslant\frac49$. Then, one of the following possibilities takes place:

$0\leqslant s\leqslant\frac19$; then $t\leqslant\frac59$ and so, since $f(s)\leqslant\frac14$ and $f(t)\leqslant\frac12$, $|f(t)-f(s)|\leqslant\frac12$.
$\frac19\leqslant s\leqslant\frac29$; then $t\leqslant\frac23$ and so, since $f(s)=\frac14$ and $f(t)\leqslant\frac12$, $|f(t)-f(s)|\leqslant\frac14$.
$\frac29\leqslant s\leqslant\frac13$; then $t\leqslant\frac79$ and so, since $f(s)\geqslant\frac14$ and $f(t)\leqslant\frac34$, $|f(t)-f(s)|\leqslant\frac12$.
$\frac13\leqslant s$; then, since $f(s)=\frac12$ and $f(s)\leqslant f(t)\leqslant1$, $|f(t)-f(s)|\leqslant\frac12$.

This shows that $\omega\left(\frac49\right)\leqslant\frac12$. But $f(0)=0$, $f\left(\frac13\right)=\frac12$, and $\frac13-0=\frac13\leqslant\frac49$. Therefore, $\omega\left(\frac49\right)=\frac12$.
Since $\omega\left(\frac49\right)=\frac12$ and $\omega$ is increasing, $\omega\left(\frac13\right)\leqslant\frac12$. But, again, since $f(0)=0$, $f\left(\frac13\right)=\frac12$, and $\frac13-0=\frac13\leqslant\frac12$, $\omega\left(\frac13\right)=\frac12$. So, the restriction of $\omega$ to $\left[\frac13,\frac49\right]$ is constant.
But the same argument shows that, for each $n\in\Bbb N$, the restriction of $\omega$ to$$\left[\frac1{3^{n}},\frac4{3^{n+1}}\right]\label{a}\tag1$$is constant (it always takes the value $2^{-n}$ there). Since, for every $\varepsilon>0$, the interval $[0,\varepsilon]$ contains intervals of the form \ref{a}, the restriction of $\omega$ to $[0,\varepsilon]$ is not strictly increasing.

Op's question: is $\omega$ necessarily strictly increasing on an interval containing $0$, unless $f$ is constant?

@geetha290krm I have edited my question. What do you think now?
